# Unable to plug string converted to bool into if statement in JAVA

Tags: java, string, boolean

I'm a beginner sorry if this is obvious. I've got an exercise I'm trying to finish and can't seem to figure out. I've got the logic of the program down. I'm supposed to guess what type of mushroom someone is thinking of with 3 questions out of 6 mushrooms.

They all have characteristics. I've got a decision tree with Yes and NO answers on paper that's going to give me the answer as to what the person is guessing.

The problem i run into when trying to code this in Java is that the IF statement that i'm trying to use refuses the variable String I'm inputing (type mismatch) even tough I've made that string equal to a boolean value.

I've tried with `parse.Boolean()` and `Valueof()` and neither has worked. I've tried simply to do

`boolean oui = true;`

Then I tried

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Champi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner clavier = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Pensez a un champignon : amanite tue mouches, pied bleu, girolle,");
        System.out.println("cèpe de Bordeaux, coprin chevelu ou agaric jaunissant.");

        boolean oui = true;
        boolean Oui = true;
        boolean non = false;
        boolean Non = false;



        System.out.print("Est-ce que votre champignon a un anneau (true : oui, false : non) ? ");
        String Reponse1 = clavier.nextLine(); 

        if (Reponse1) {
            System.out.print("l'agaric jaunissant");
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("l'amanite tue-mouches");}
```

The desired behavior is of course that the user would enter "Yes" or "oui" (as this is done in french) into the input and for the IF statement to convert that to "True" or "No" converted to "False"
Nothing seems to work !

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the line that was readed with the words you want to analise.

```
 if(Response1.toLowerCase().equals("oui") || Response1.toLowerCase().equals("yes")){
       //Statements when true...

 }else{
      // Statements when false...
}
```

Comment: Wow it worked !! it needed another ) at the end since the ("yes") uses up the parenthesis that threw me a bit but other than that thank sir it's amazing I can complete my program and you answers super quickly !!!

Comment: One question, what is .toLowerCase() in this function ? I've tried with uppercase and it works too... what gives ?

Comment: That is only to make sure regardless the way the user type (yes, Yes,yEs,yeS,YES...) the string will be the same value as the literal one in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In java, if-statement only accepts boolean types. In your case, you're trying to pass String object into if statement.
Looking at the logic, I think you're trying to firstly parse yes/no in the French language. So, you can combine both processes by passing string check into if statement:

```java
String Reponse1 = clavier.nextLine();
if("oui".equals(Response1.toLowerCase()) || "yes".equals(Response1.toLowerCase())) {
    //positive answer
} else {
//negative
}
```

Comparing string instead of `Response1` won't raise exception even if `Response1` will be `null`. Though, if you like to you can make it the other way around

```java
if(Response1.toLowerCase().equals("oui") Response1.toLowerCase().equals("yes")) {
    //positive answer
} else {
//negative
}
```

Notice, however, that you can't use `==` when comparing the strings because it will compare addresses of an object and not the strings itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! What do you mean by "addresses of an object and not the strings itself." ?

Comment: @AndreaDavidEdelman Each object has a unique address in memory. If a program wants to get the value of some variable, it'll look up its value by this address.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is not working is because the inputted value is kept in the variable `Reponse1`. Even though the text may be the same as the name for a variable, it does not become that variable.

The contents of a string are just letters in order. They do not correspond to names of variables in any way.

You can use `toLowerCase()` on a string to convert it to all lower case letters, which lets you avoid capitalization differences. 
Then, to check if a string matches another one, just use the `equals` method.

```
String Reponse1 = clavier.nextLine();
Reponse1 = Reponse1.toLowerCase();
if(Reponse1.equals("oui") || Reponse1.equals("yes")) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I notice you didn't use "to lower case" unlike the others ? Why is that ?

Comment: @AndreaDavidEdelman I did use it, but it is right above the `if`. The line `Reponse1 = Reponse1.toLowerCase();` stores the lower case version in the variable. This helps avoid the 2 uses of it that other answers have. Their method simply checks the lower case value but does not keep it, resulting in an additional use for another possible value. Avoiding repetition can help make your code easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now, brilliant it is indeed easier to read ! I think I'll do it like that ! thanks !